# How many instances of vm_area_struct can be there

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I got this section from Robert love

The vm_area_struct structure describes a single memory area over a contiguous 
interval in a given address space.

Question : So this means only one vm_area_struct is there to refer to the single contiguous memory, or for each user / kernel thread we have a vm_area_struct instance ?

Answer (score 0):

vm_area_struct have single virtual contiguous memory,for one user there may be many vm_area_struct.

Comment: here user means process ?

Comment: yes user and process does not have such restriction .